# Format the date string "2013-08-26T12:00:00.000"

Tags: php, string, date

The date is represented by a string "2013-08-26T12:00:00.000". How to format this date string in the following way?: "2013-08-26 12:00:00"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2013-08-26T12:00:00.000"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$time = strtotime("2013-08-26T12:00:00.000");
echo strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $time);
```

Comment: It says boolean false

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution, use PHP's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2013-08-26T12:00:00.000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

```
$x = new DateTime('2013-08-26T12:00:00.000');
$x->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```